# how to remove language prefix from rewriting administrator url in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

Recently i was asked to move a site to a new server. The site is on Joomla 2.5.1.7 and has 2 languages. The move seemed smooth but when i tried to access the administrator, i got a 404 page.

What happens is this: after typing the url for the admin/login page (www.mysite.com/administrator) this address changes to www.mysite.com/el/administrator and isnt recognized. So i dont have access to the backend at all and all changes must be made via ftp and on the db directly. At the live site this doesnt happen and everything works as intended.

I checked the .htaccess and is the default of the installation. The php ver of the two servers are almost the same (5.4 and 5.4.41).

The site has many modules and virtuemart but the one responsible i think is Falang. When i deactivated it almost nothing changes and the rewrite still happens.

Any clues and ideas?

Comment: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=617&t=713477#p2794600

Comment: I realize that you may have to do that via PHPMyAdmin, but it may be a solution. Also, http://joomla.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you, the option was already set to No. I will also try posting at your second link that is more focused on Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunetly the solution was dissapointing. Somewhere between zipping, downloading, uploading to the new server and extracting something went wrong and some files were corrupted or not copied.

Solution was to use akeeba backup and do the whole proccess again, where everything worked at once as they should.